# Context API history.listen cannot read property 'listen' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, browser-history, react-context

I am using React hooks Context API with Browser History PUSH and POP state. Currently getting this error `Cannot read property 'listen' of undefined`. If I move my Browser History function to another component then it works perfectly with no errors. I didn't include all my states in the code below. Any help will be awesome thanks guys ...

```
import React, { useState, createContext, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

const history = useHistory()
const [keys, setKeys] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
return history.listen(location => {
    if (history.action === 'PUSH') { 
    setKeys([location.key])
    }
    if (history.action === 'POP') {
    if (keys[1] === location.key) { 
        setKeys(([ _, ...keys ]) => keys) 
        setPage(page + 1)
        setCount(count + 1) 
        setPercentage(percentage + 20)
    } else { 
        setKeys((keys) => [ location.key, ...keys ]) 
        setPage(page - 1) 
        setCount(count - 1) 
        setPercentage(percentage - 20) 
    }
    }
})
}, [keys, count, percentage])
```

Comment: Are you rendering a `<BrowserRouter>` farther up the component tree than this component? You said it worked in another component so i suspect your browser router is a descendant of this component, when it needs to be an ancestor.

Comment: No, my Context API is my Management state and wrapped all my routes. It worked in another component that has it's own rest API. Just adding the function above I can browse history with no errors. Do I need to initialize it somehow?